# Extending a list

Tags: list-manipulation, random, algorithm

I have a range of n integers (always starting at 1) which are 1 apart, f.e. `Range[10]`, `Range[17]` or `Range[100]`.

I want to extend the range by `[1, 2, 3 ... n]` elements by duplicating `n` existing elements at random positions. With `n = 2` for example `Range[10]` could become

> {1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12}

There are 3 requirements:

(1) The first and the last element should not be duplicated.

(2)  After a duplication there should be a jump of 2 (like from 3 to 5 in the above example list).

(3) There should be at least 1 non-repeated element between 2 duplications (5 and 6 in the list).

I finally found an ugly solution with `For`s and `While`s but somehow got lost trying to find a functional one.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. You state "I want to extend the range by `[1, 2, 3 ... n]` elements", but `[1, 2, 3 ... n]` has no meaning to me as a _Mathematica_ expression nor as a mathematical one. You mention duplicating elements, but your example doesn't show duplication as I understand it; it shows `... k, k + 1, ...` being replaced by `... k, k, ...` and then `n + 1` tacked onto the end of a list that previously had `n` elements. So I'm confused about what your goal really is. Perhaps you should add your ugly but working code. The code at least would give a precise specification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f[m_, n_] := Module[{rg, ok, rs},
  rg = Range[m + n];
  ok = rg[[2 ;; -2]];
  While[True,
   rs = Sort@RandomSample[ok, n];
   If[FreeQ[Differences@rs, 1 | 2], Break[]]];
  Fold[ReplacePart[#1, #2 + 1 -> #2] &, rg, rs]]

f[10, 2]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 12}

Comment: Beautiful combination of `Fold` and `ReplacePart`. Sometimes I get two duplicate pairs next to each other like `4,4,5,5`. Not a big deal, but I asked for a separation (point 3 of the question).

Comment: @eldo - Ok, fixed that with `FreeQ[ ... , 1 | 2]`

Comment: The ``While`` loop and ``RandomSample`` may be problematic for large inputs because it would be unlikely that ``Differences@rs`` do not have any $1$s or $2$s. For example, ``f[81,40]`` would take a long time to calculate.

Answer (score 4):

This would work:

```
ExtendedList[range_, duplicates_] := 
 MapAt[# - 1 &, Range[range], 
  List /@ Accumulate[Most[RandomChoice[
    Flatten[Permutations /@ 
     IntegerPartitions[range - 2 duplicates, {duplicates + 1}],
     1]
   ]] + 2]
 ]
```

The above code is not efficient for large lists. The code below would be more efficient:

```
ExtendedList[range_, duplicates_] := 
 MapAt[# - 1 &, Range[range], 
  List /@ Accumulate[Most[RandomSample[RandomChoice[
     IntegerPartitions[range - 2 duplicates, {duplicates + 1}]
   ]]] + 2]
 ]
```

**Edit:** The above codes generate a list of length `range`: the length does not change. You would need to type `ExtendedList[12,2]` instead of `[10,2]` in order to get the result in the question.

**Edit 2:** Fixed the code.

```
ExtendedList[range_, duplicates_] := 
 MapAt[# - 1 &, Range[range + duplicates], 
  List /@ Accumulate[Most[RandomSample[RandomChoice[
     IntegerPartitions[range - duplicates, {duplicates + 1}]
   ]]] + 2]
 ]

ExtendedList[10,2]
(*{1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11, 12}*)
```

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot, +1

Comment: These codes have one flaw: they subtract 1 from certain elements instead of duplicating elements. So, you would need to input the final length of the list (initial length + number of duplicates) and the number of duplicates in order to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, but that's not a big problem

Comment: Fixed the code!

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
Clear[f, m, n];
f[m_, n_] := SequenceReplace[Range[m + n]
  , {k : Repeated[_, {n}], c_, Repeated[_, {n - 1}]} :> 
   Splice@{k, Splice@ConstantArray[c, n]}
  , If[Mod[m + n, 2 n] == 0
   , Quotient[m + n, 2 n] - 1
   , Quotient[m + n, 2 n]]
  ]
```

---

*Explanation:*

The `SequenceReplace` command starts with an extended list with `m + n` entries. It replaces the entry `c_` (following `n` repeated entries) by a `ConstantArray` of `n` such `c`s. Further, it removes the following `n-1` entries. If the list divides evenly by `2n`, then it doesn't make the last replacement (using the third argument of `SequenceReplace` which is the number of replacements) in order to keep the last entry in place (as required) using the `If` command that uses the `Mod` and the `Quotient` commands.

---

*Examples:*

```
f[10, 2]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12}

```
f[13, #] & /@ Range[5]
```

[image]

---

*Visualization*

```
fvis[m_, n_] := 
 SequenceReplace[
  Range[m + n], {k : Repeated[_, {n}], c_, Repeated[_, {n - 1}]} :>
   Splice@{k
     , Splice@(Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ ConstantArray[c, n])}
  , If[Mod[m + n, 2 n] == 0
   , Quotient[m + n, 2 n] - 1
   , Quotient[m + n, 2 n]]
  ]

fvis[13, #] & /@ Range[5]
```

[image]